# Zoom imagen dentro de un div

Tags: css

Tengo un div con imágenes en miniaturas que al pasar el cursor por encima les hace zoom, el problema es que las que están en los bordes se salen fuera y no se visualizan enteras, supongo que tiene que haber alguna forma con css de limitar los margenes del div y que se agranden pero adaptándose a el. Googleando no encuentro nada y ya no se me ocurren mas palabras clave :S

```
.zoomIt{
    display:inline-block!important;
    -webkit-transition:-webkit-transform 1s ease-out;
    transition:transform 0.5s ease-out;
    margin-top:px;
}
.zoomIt:hover{
    margin-top:;
    -webkit-transform: scale(2);
    transform: scale(2)
}
```

Este es el css con el que hago zoom a la imagen.

Comment: Es el div contenedor el que limita lo que se ve de la imagen o es que se salen de la pantalla?

Answer (score 3):

Asegúrate de que no tengas definido `overflow: hidden` en el contenedor de las imágenes, por defecto deberían verse completas:

```css
div img:hover {
 transform: scale(4);
 z-index: 100;
}

div {
  display: inline-table;
  background-color: goldenrod;
  padding: 5px;
}

#recorta {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div>
<p>Sin overflow definido</p>
<img alt="Demo" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50"/>

<img alt="Demo" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50"/>



</div>

<div id="recorta">
<p>Con <strong>overflow : hidden</strong></p>
<img alt="Demo" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50"/>

<img alt="Demo" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50"/>



</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

En el siguiente código, el evento `onmouseover` significa que la función se ejecutará cuando pasamos el cursor encima del objeto con id, el efecto `onmouseout` será cuando movemos el cursor fuera del objeto; en el primero puse que la `transition` sea de 1 segundo y la imagen tendrá una escala de 1.5; y al mover el cursor fuera del objeto su escala será de 0.9; pero primero puse en el estilo de la imagen que su escala sea también de 0.9; o sea, vuelve a la normalidad.

Puse `overflow:hidden;` para que el div se ponga al frente de la imagen.

Esto te puede servir, tal vez sea lo que necesites:

```js
var f=document.getElementById("im").style;
function i(){
  f.transform="scale(1.5)";
  f.transitionDuration="1s";}
function o(){f.transform="scale(0.9)";}
```

```html
<div style="width:235px;padding:30px">
<div style="padding:5px;overflow:hidden">
<img style="scale:(0.9)" onmouseover="i()" onmouseout="o()" id="im" src="https://intranet.virgenmedallamilagrosa.com/assets/images/insignia.png">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tal vez sea lo que necesite, pero tal vez podrías haber puesto algún comentario que le ayude a los demás a entender lo que hace y cómo lo hace, las respuestas que contienen sólo código no son tan útiles como las que contienen comentarios explicando el código, y al fin y al cabo aquí estamos intentando ayudar a toda la gente que podamos, pedirles que copien y peguen sin entender, no ayuda mucho.

Comment: El evento onmouseover significa que la funcion se ejecutará cuando pasamos el cursor encima del objeto con id, el efecto onmouseout sera cuando movemos el cursor fuera del objeto; en el primero puse que la transition sea de 1 segundo y la imagen tendrá una escala de 1.5; y al mover el cursor fuera del objeto su escala sera de 0.9; pero primero puse en el estilo de la imagen que su escala sea tambien de 0.9; o sea, vuelve a la normalidad.
Puse overflow:hidden; para que el div se ponga al frente de la imagen.

Answer (score 0):

En mi código utilizo JavaScript y el "zoomIn" pasa al hacer click sobre la imagen.
también puedes hacer click fuera del grupo de imágenes par un "zoomOut"  Si no te gusta lo de `click` puedes cambiarlo por `mouseover`.

Por favor lea los comentarios en el JavaScript.

Importante: cada imagen tiene un atributo `data-transform_origin` para controlar la transformación de las imágenes.

```js
// el array de las imagenes class .zoomIt
let zit = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".zoomIt"));
//Estoy iterando las imágenes con el método map, pero tu puedes utilizar el método que más te guste
zit.map((img) =>{img.addEventListener("click", (e)=>{
// al hacer click en una imagen guardo el valor para transform-origen en una variable
  let to = img.dataset.transform_origin;
  // establecer un estilo comun para todas las imágenes
  zit.map((_img)=>{
    _img.zoom = false;
    _img.setAttribute("style","z-index:0;transform:scale(1);")
  });
  // establecer el estilo de la imagen escogida por el usuario
  img.zoom = true;
  img.setAttribute("style",`z-index:2;transform-origin:${to};transform:scale(1.5);`)
})               
})
//si haces click fuera del contenedor todas las imágenes vuelven al estilo original
document.body.addEventListener("click", (e)=>{if(e.target.tagName !== "IMG"){
  zit.map((img)=>{
    let to = img.dataset.transform_origin;
    let zi = img.zoom ? 2 : 0;
    img.setAttribute("style",`z-index:${zi};transform-origin:${to};transform:scale(1);`)
  });
}});
```

```css
*{margin:0;padding:0;}
body{height:100vh;overflow:hidden;}
#contenedor{
  display:flex; 
  flex-wrap:wrap; 
  width:300px;
  height:300px;}

.zoomIt{
    z-index:0;
    flex:0 0 33%;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    display:inline-block;
    transform: scale(1);
    transition:transform 1s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div id="contenedor">
<img data-transform_origin="0 0" class="zoomIt"  src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/darwin300.jpg" alt ="Darwin" />
  <img data-transform_origin="50% 0"  class="zoomIt" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/darwin300.jpg" alt ="Darwin" />
  <img data-transform_origin="100% 0" class="zoomIt" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/darwin300.jpg" alt ="Darwin" />
  
  <img data-transform_origin="0 50%;"  class="zoomIt" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/darwin300.jpg" alt ="Darwin" /> 
  <img data-transform_origin="50% 50%"  class="zoomIt"  src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/darwin300.jpg" alt ="Darwin" />
  <img data-transform_origin="100% 50%"  class="zoomIt" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/darwin300.jpg" alt ="Darwin" />
  
  <img data-transform_origin="0 100%"  class="zoomIt" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/darwin300.jpg" alt ="Darwin" />
  <img data-transform_origin="50% 100%"  class="zoomIt" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/darwin300.jpg" alt ="Darwin" />
  <img data-transform_origin="100% 100%"  class="zoomIt" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/darwin300.jpg" alt ="Darwin" />
  <div>
```

Espero que sea útil.